# What causes the error: Viewstate verification failed. Reason: The viewstate supplied failed integrity check?

Tags: c#, view, viewstate, state

I'm using a single server to host the application, and between 15h and 00h i had 1200 error of invalid viewstate, what can cause this error? in this specify moment? The Event Viewer do not report anything about, only report the error, any other log explains the reason.

Comment: This is not answerable without more information. Start with (a sample of) the errorlogs.

Answer (score 0):

Just saw this question. In case you still have not solved it, or for the benefit of other users here is my solution. I had a similar problem and it was being caused by parts of the page being loaded through AJAX and each on of them having its own view state fields that were conflicting with the view state fields of the main page. I solved it by totally removing the view state fields from the Ajax pages. Here is how I did it:

http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/How-to-disable-or-remove-ViewState-Hidden-Field-in-ASP.Net-Page.aspx